# Button view with drawableLeft

Tags: android, button, drawable

I need to add drawable to my button and added drawableLeft to it. If button's width is set to wrap_content, then everything is fine and looks good. But if I set custom width to my button then drawableLeft image goes away from button's caption to left edge of the button. Is this somekind of a design bug in android? How can I fix this to let button look the same on custom width?

Regards,
evilone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that x-position of the `drawableLeft` depends on left padding and x-scroll position: [source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/TextView.java;h=68600cf90a59cbc162b71d74b935ad99313a2c32;hb=HEAD). So that's by-design behavior. I think you'd better use `SpannableString` and `ImageSpan` classes to display an image to the left of the button's text:

```
final SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder("\uFFFC");
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable)),
    0, builder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
builder.append(getString(R.string.your_string));
textView.setText(builder);
```

Also, you can use `Html.fromHtml()` method to build `Spannable` from HTML. But in this case you need to implement `Html.ImageGetter` interface to load images from resources.

**EDIT**: There's a way to do a button-like widget using only XML:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="200dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:src="@drawable/button_icon"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:text="@string/button_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I added some info to the answer.

Comment: can I do it somehow in my design XML?

Comment: I don't know any way to do this in XML. But I added a piece of code that'll help you to do similar thing using XML.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to your button attributes.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_btn_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem just right now, but I found out that you just need to set **android:padding** to the button. That way you push the picture away from left side of the button. Check this code:

```
`<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:text="@string/string1"
        android:textSize="16sp" />`
```